# ElasticSearch multiple queries in one

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using ElasticSearch and I want to make a query.

I have differents modules: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.
where `a` and  `b` have an extra value (`companyId`) I need to filter the text of all modules, but I need to filter the `companyId` just for `a` and `b` not for modules `c` and `d`.

This will look something like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (modules in ('a', 'b') and companyId='myid') OR (modules in ('b', 'c'))`

But I have this:

```
client.search({
      index: INDEX,
      type: TYPE,
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: {
              match: { text: 'mytext' },
            },
            filter: [
              { terms: { module: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] } },
              { term: { companyId: 'myid' } },
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Thanks a lot if you can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below query is what you are looking for. I've implemented the `OR` operator i.e. `should` inside the `filter`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": { "text": "mytext" }
      },
      "filter": [
       {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      { "match": { "module": "a" }},
                      { "match": { "companyId": "1" }}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      { "match": { "module": "b" }},
                      { "match": { "companyId": "1" }}
                   ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": {
                    "match": { "module": "c" }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": {
                    "match": { "module": "d" }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```